# Requiring one element without attributes XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm just getting started with XSD trying to validate an XML configuration file I've been using. Each configuration specifies a default configuration for a server, which can be overridden on a per-server basis.

This is the default:

```
 <server>
  <cpu>65</cpu>
  // Other configuration
 </server>
```

This is an (optional) override:

```
 <server key="2">
  <cpu>55</cpu>
 </server>
```

I'm not sure how to build the XSD to support 1 required element without attributes, and 0-n elements with attributes *given that they have the same name*. With different names, it's a much easier matter, but that seems messy given that the elements are otherwise identical.

Edit:

To address @kjhughes's request, here's the simplified document structure:

```
<configuration>
  <target>Production</target>
  <responsible>email@email.com</responsible>
  <server>
    <cpu>65</cpu>
  </server>
  <server key="2">
    <cpu>55</cpu>
  </server>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You cannot have different elements of the same name within the same content model.**

But you change the name of your second `server` elements to reflect that they are server *overrides*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="try.xsd">
  <target>Production</target>
  <responsible>email@email.com</responsible>
  <server>
    <cpu>65</cpu>
  </server>
  <server-override key="2">
    <cpu>55</cpu>
  </server-override>
</configuration>
```

**And still share their commonality in the type definitions via extension:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="configuration">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="target"/>
        <xs:element name="responsible"/>
        <xs:element name="server" type="server-type"
                 minOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="server-override" type="server-override-type"
                 minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="server-type">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="cpu"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="server-override-type">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="server-type">
        <xs:attribute name="key" use="required"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I was afraid that was going to be the case browsing over the specification. Using the extensions will make this a lot easier, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try JAXB unmarshalling, you create java objects that can be used to unmarshal the XML, this makes it easier to handle the XML 
Use the xsd for generationg the jaxb objects
Depending on what IDE you have in eclipse you only need to right click your xmlroot and press generate jaxb,,,

Comment: The problem is I don't have the XSD yet (I'm also not using Java).